# (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading

Tags: angularjs, angular, primeng

I am getting the below error. I recently updated `primeng` to its latest version after which I got this error. I am not sure what is wrong and trying really hard on the google to find answers as I am new to angular type of programming.

I tried the following steps:

- tried deprecating `primeng` back to `beta17`, but no luck
- tried importing `traceur` package, still no luck
- tried `primeng rc1`, no luck

Could you please let me know what is the actual issue and how should I go about resolving this?

> localhost/:38 Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:57799/node_modules/traceur/bin/traceur.js
>       Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:57799/node_modules/traceur/bin/traceur.js
>           at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:57799/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:647:29)
>           at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:57799/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:236:37)
>           at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:57799/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:136:47)
>           at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:57799/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:304:33)
>       Error loading http://localhost:57799/node_modules/traceur/bin/traceur.js
>       Unable to load transpiler to transpile http://localhost:57799/node_modules/primeng/components/common/api.js
>       Error loading http://localhost:57799/node_modules/primeng/components/common/api.js as "./components/common/api" from http://localhost:57799/node_modules/primeng/primeng.js
>           at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:57799/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:647:29)
>           at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:57799/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:236:37)
>           at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:57799/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:136:47)
>           at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:57799/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:304:33)
>       Error loading http://localhost:57799/node_modules/traceur/bin/traceur.js
>       Unable to load transpiler to transpile http://localhost:57799/node_modules/primeng/components/common/api.js
>       Error loading http://localhost:57799/node_modules/primeng/components/common/api.js as "./components/common/api" from http://localhost:57799/node_modules/primeng/primeng.js(anonymous function) @ localhost/:38

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well a while ago. For me the solution was to change the module in the `tsconfig.json` to:

```
"module": "system"
```

After that, compile all your typescript files again

Comment: Tried that, but unfortunately had no luck. Thanks anyway.