# Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading service

Tags: angular

I'm currently trying to use a service to pass a string. However, at my `AppComponent` I'm getting `undefined` Service.

This is the error:

```
Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/services/main.service
    patchProperty/desc.set/wrapFn@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:698:26
    ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:265:21
    Zone.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:154:28
    ZoneTask/this.invoke@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:335:28

    Error loading http://localhost:3000/services/main.service as "../services/main.service" from http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js
Stack trace:
(SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/services/main.service
    patchProperty/desc.set/wrapFn@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:698:26
    ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:265:21
    Zone.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:154:28
    ZoneTask/this.invoke@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:335:28

    Error loading http://localhost:3000/services/main.service as "../services/main.service" from http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js
```

**main.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable }                   from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response }      from '@angular/http';
import { Observable }                   from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class MainService {
    private projectURL = 'http://localhost:64895/api/Process/ProcessFile';
    private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'});

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    public passFileUrl = (filePath: string): Observable<number> => {
        var json = JSON.stringify(filePath);
        return this.http.post(this.projectURL, json, {headers: this.headers})
                    .map((response: Response) => <number>response.json());
    }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MainService } from '../services/main.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'converter-utility',
  templateUrl: './app/views/main.component.html',
  providers: [MainService],
  styleUrls: ['./app/views/css/main.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  private workableFile: string;

  constructor(
    private mainService: MainService
    ) { }

  doProcess() {
    this.mainService.passFileUrl(this.workableFile)
                    .subscribe((data: any) => {
                      console.log(data);
                    });
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { MainService }   from '../services/main.service';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  providers: [
        MainService,
    ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**systemjs.config.js**

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',
      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w"
  },
  "licenses": [
    {
      "type": "MIT",
      "url": "https://github.com/angular/angular.io/blob/master/LICENSE"
    }
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~3.1.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.1.1",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.13",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.25"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.34",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.45",
    "concurrently": "^3.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.3"
  }
}
```

**The App Structure**

```
  app
   app.component.ts
   app.module.ts
   main.ts
  node_modules ...
  services
   main.service.ts
  index.html
  package.json
  styles.css
  systemjs.config.js
  tsconfig.json
```

I've tried a few solutions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40402361/3812244) with no sucess. I do realise there are lots of similar questions out there (which could classify this question as duplicated), but none that helped me to fix it.
Not to mention that I'm using Angular 2 for a few days now, so the problem may be between the chair and the keyboard. ☺
I do appreciate if you could assist me to give some directions.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post your package.json  also ?

Comment: HI @AvramVirgil, just edited and added the package.jon and the systemjs.config.js

Comment: Is the Service folder located outside of your app folder ?

Comment: Yes, @AvramVirgil.

Comment: Components, directives, Services, Pipes should be inside the app folder, assests like css, fonts, images can be outside the app folder

Comment: @AvramVirgil, I just edited to show the structure.

Comment: Modify this in app.module.ts  import { MainService } from '../services/main.service';  to import { MainService } from './services/main.service';

Comment: @AvramVirgil, by doing that it highlights red: '[ts] Cannot find module './services/main.service''

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127800/discussion-between-avram-virgil-and-aurometal).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Resolution:

Move the service folder inside the app folder, correct the imports so they point to the correct location this will fix the 404 error.

To use the service folder outside the app folder:

Open systemjs.config.js

Add:

```
var map = {
    'services' : '/services', 
};
```

Comment: hI @Avram VIrgil, if you could edit this answer please as per our conversation regarding the app structure, I'll accept it. Indeed,by moving the services folder inside the app resolved the issue. moreover, I'd love to get an explanation of why my structure failed. Thanks!

Comment: You can use the folder outside the app folder but you need to modify the systemjs.config.js to let angular know about the existence of that folder

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the string specified in the `from` section should resolve to a file. For instance, the following import statement:

```
import { MainService } from '../services/main.service';
```

Without extra configuration, SystemJS tries to load the file '../services/main.service' (note: no extension).

**Option 1:** configure SystemJS to add the default extension of '.js' for your code. See the [SystemJS Configuration API reference](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md) for multiple ways to do it.

**Option 2:** Specify the `.js` extension in your import statement. This is a TypeScript feature that was originally discussed [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4595).

Personally, I prefer the first option.

Comment: Hi Ronald, the systemjs.config.js defaults the extension to 'js' already, which satisfies your option 1. Tried option 2, without luck.

Comment: @AuroMetal If the services folder is outside the app folder, your current SystemJS config doesn't set the default extensions for them - they are set only for the `app` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Below solution working for me -

Move the service folder inside the app folder, correct the imports so they point to the correct location this will fix the 404 error.

To use the service folder outside the app folder:

Open systemjs.config.js

Add:

var map = {
'services' : '/services',
};